# return a list of objects depending on a boolean of a variable of a custom object

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking to return a list of menus depending on a boolean of a variable of a custom object(`AvailableService`).

Something like this

```
class Menu{
List<SubMenu> subMenus;
} 

class SubMenu{
AvailableService;
}

class AvailableService{
bool supportsDelivery;
bool supportsCollection;
bool supportsTable;
}
```

I need to filter the menus to return menus that `supportsDelivery`;

I've tried the below, but that returns all the submenu's irrespective of the `supportsDelivery` `bool` value.

```
 List<Menu> menus = menus.where((m) => m.submenus.toList().where((s) => s.availableService.supportsDelivery = true).isNotEmpty).toList();
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. What you provided is not valid dart. That said, the issue is likely you made a type and have `=` instead of `==`.  You should also not being doing explicit comparisons to literal bools. Again, this is unclear because the rest of the code is invalid.

Comment: ok  will redo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I hope I understood you correctly and have created proper dataset. Also I've improved all classes.

The best option is to move all possible logic inside a class with a proper naming. Since then it is more readable and it is easier to find a bug.

Also I allowed myself to create an extension on `List<Menu>` to avoid duplicated logic in the future. It contains the solution.

```
class Menu {
  final List<SubMenu> subMenus;

  Menu(this.subMenus);

  bool get doesContainItemWithDeliverySupport =>
      onlyWithSupportedDelivery.length > 0;

  List<SubMenu> get onlyWithSupportedDelivery =>
      subMenus.where((submenu) => submenu.doesSupportDelivery).toList();

  @override
  String toString() => 'Menu(subMenus: $subMenus)\n\n';
}

class SubMenu {
  final AvailableService availableService;

  SubMenu(this.availableService);

  bool get doesSupportDelivery => availableService.doesSupportDelivery;

  @override
  String toString() => 'SubMenu(availableService: $availableService)\n';
}

class AvailableService {
  final bool supportsDelivery;
  final bool supportsCollection;
  final bool supportsTable;

  AvailableService(
    this.supportsDelivery,
    this.supportsCollection,
    this.supportsTable,
  );

  bool get doesSupportDelivery => true == supportsDelivery;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'AvailableService(supportsDelivery: $supportsDelivery, supportsCollection: $supportsCollection, supportsTable: $supportsTable)';
}

extension on List<Menu> {
  List<Menu> get onlyWithSupportedDelivery {
    var filteredMenus = <Menu>[];

    forEach((menu) {
      if (menu.doesContainItemWithDeliverySupport) {
        filteredMenus.add(Menu(menu.onlyWithSupportedDelivery));
      }
    });

    return filteredMenus;
  }
}

main() {
  final menu1 = Menu([
    SubMenu(
      AvailableService(
        true,
        true,
        true,
      ),
    ),
    SubMenu(
      AvailableService(
        false,
        true,
        true,
      ),
    ),
    SubMenu(
      AvailableService(
        true,
        false,
        true,
      ),
    ),
    SubMenu(
      AvailableService(
        true,
        true,
        false,
      ),
    ),
  ]);

  final menu2 = Menu([
    SubMenu(
      AvailableService(
        true,
        true,
        true,
      ),
    ),
    SubMenu(
      AvailableService(
        false,
        true,
        true,
      ),
    ),
  ]);

  final menu3 = Menu([
    SubMenu(
      AvailableService(
        false,
        true,
        true,
      ),
    ),
  ]);

  final menus = <Menu>[menu1, menu2, menu3];
  var filteredMenus = menus.onlyWithSupportedDelivery;

  filteredMenus.forEach((menu) => print(menu));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer. I was just going to a  a minimal reproducible example but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are assigning a new value to support delivery, you should use the following code instead:

```
 List<Menu> menus = menus.where((m) => m.submenus.toList().where((s) => s.availableService.supportsDelivery).isNotEmpty).toList();
```

This is because the where method uses the function you specify to check whether it should return the element. In your case the function was

```
(s) => s.availableService.supportsDelivery = True
```

But this function does not return True or False; it returns null. That's because = is for used for value assignment. You should use == for boolean operation. So you should replace = with ==. But using value == True is similar to directly returning the value (in your case at least).

```
(s) => s.availableService.supportsDelivery == True
```

which is equal to

```
(s) => s.availableService.supportsDelivery
```